# Osmdroid 5.1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I cannot even create a simple map. I'm using `osmdroid-android-5.1` library and from what I understand that I don't need to add the `slf4j` library from 5.0 version and above.

My `activity_main.xml` is as follows:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and the `content_main.xml` contains the map as follows:

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tilesource="Mapnik" />
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I hit on the activity_main preview, I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.osmdroid.tileprovider.constants.OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants
    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderArray.getMapTile(MapTileProviderArray.java:93)
    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay$1.handleTile(TilesOverlay.java:185)
    at org.osmdroid.util.TileLooper.loop(TileLooper.java:34)
    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.drawTiles(TilesOverlay.java:164)
    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.TilesOverlay.draw(TilesOverlay.java:151)
    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onDraw(DefaultOverlayManager.java:107)
    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:1008)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1077)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16090)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16088)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:431)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:428)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea where the error might be and cannot achieve something so simple (unless I don't see anything obvious)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

osmdroid doesn't provide the "preview" that intellij is trying to render. That constants class is trying to scan for local storage to use as a download cache. It can probably be handled better.

Anyhow, to solve your problem, just hit the play button and run the app. It should work just fine on an android device or emulator